# HTML5 Flexbox stretching possible in both axis?

Tags: html, flexbox

I have a flexbox div that allows a SINGLE child element.  So far I've been able to get alignments of the child working nicely (top, left, right, bottom, etc), including vertical stretch.  I also want to be able to support horizontal stretch at the same time as vertical ('at the same time' seems to be the key).

I've been able to accomplish horizontal stretch by setting the 'flex' property to '1 100%' on the child element, however this appears to ignore any padding applied to the parent element(and any margin applied to the child node for that matter).

Looking at the flexbox spec, I'm not able to find any other way to do this along the main axis of the flexbox.  Cross-axis stretch is no problem.

Comment: I found it.  The property I was looking for is 'flex 1 0px', which works in the latest version s of Chromium(v20), but not the current Chrome release (v18).

Tested in Chromium v20+ and Dartium v20+

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. And here is a small sample which shows you how:

```css
.centerbox {
  /* basic styling */
  width: 350px;
  height: 95px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border: 1px solid #555;
  background: #CFC;
  /* flexbox, por favor */
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  display: -moz-box;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-pack: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  display: box;
  box-orient: horizontal;
  box-pack: center;
  box-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .centerbox {
      /* basic styling */
      width: 350px;
      height: 95px;
      font-size: 14px;
      border: 1px solid #555;
      background: #CFC;
      /* flexbox, por favor */
      display: -webkit-box;
      -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      display: -moz-box;
      -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
      -moz-box-pack: center;
      -moz-box-align: center;
      display: box;
      box-orient: horizontal;
      box-pack: center;
      box-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="centerbox">
    <textarea>resize me, please</textarea>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

FYI: Axel Russell did some great work on writing a class for multi browser support: http://infrequently.org/2009/08/css-3-progress/

Answer (score 0):

Although you found your solution, I think the next snippet could be handy to all developers (such as myself) who searched for a general solution.
http://jsfiddle.net/EL2KL/1/
I'd be happy if you publish fiddle with your solution.

p.s. thanks to Jiri (the flex master)